# Upgrading from MySQL 4.7 to 5.5, problematic date fields

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I get this error in a legacy application running SQL from JSP pages (not my app):

> java.sql.SQLException: Value '7Some text from a field123133 2001-09-2012001-10-01 08:37:1910000-00-00
>   00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

It looks like the fields are concatenated and that is what the timestamp (and date, and datetime) is trying to decipher. Everything works fine if I run the query in mysql client and if I remove all date, datetime and timestamp fields. This happens when executeQuery(query) is run.

What I've done:

- mysqldump the old database
- imported to the new
- changed the old mysql driver to mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
- removed any old jdbc libraries
- tomcat is running on java 1.7

I'm guessing it's a problem with libraries.

- apache-tomcat-7.0.42
- 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
- jdk1.7.0_15

Here's the tomcat/lib:

activation.jar       catalina-tribes.jar    el-api.jar           jmxtools.jar                         naming-factory.jar  poolman.xml        tomcat-i18n-es.jar
annotations-api.jar  commons-codec-1.4.jar  hssf-serializer.jar  jsp-api.jar                          NetComponents.jar   servlet-api.jar    tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
catalina-ant.jar     cos.jar                jasper-el.jar        log4j.jar                            pg73jdbc3.jar       tomcat-api.jar     tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
catalina-ha.jar      dnsjava.jar            jasper.jar           mail.jar                             poi-hssf.jar        tomcat-coyote.jar  tomcat-jdbc.jar
catalina.jar         ecj-4.2.2.jar          jmxri.jar            mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar  poolman.jar         tomcat-dbcp.jar    tomcat-util.jar

And a few in the WEB-INF/lib:

fop.jar  jce1_2_1.jar  jsse.jar  NetaxeptClientVirtual.jar  soap.jar  w3c.jar  xerces.jar

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

> ?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

to the connection URL solved the problem.